# DynamoDB how to append to a list of nested objects?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

In DynamoDB I have a table named `Property`, which contains a list of nested objects called `listings`. I want to be able to add a `listing` object to the `Property` table, but it seems like DynamoDB does not support complex objects. I've tried the below, but received `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: value type: class com.listii.data.model.response.ListingResponse`.

Do I have to transform the `listing` object to a map of Strings containing all of its attributes before updating? Is there an easier way?

```
DynamoDB dynamoDb = new DynamoDB(client);
        Table propertyTable = dynamoDb.getTable("Property");

        ListingResponse listingItem = this.getListingById(listingId);
        ValueMap map = new ValueMap().withList(":listingToAttach", Arrays.asList(listingItem));

        UpdateItemSpec updateItemSpec = new UpdateItemSpec()
                .withPrimaryKey("propertyId", propertyId)
                .withUpdateExpression("SET listings = list_append(listings, :listingToAttach)")
                .withValueMap(map);

        return propertyTable.updateItem(updateItemSpec);
```

Comment: Were you able to resolve this ? If yes, could you please share json and java snippet please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using Indexes. First get the index of the listing you want to update (can use a basic for loop). Then, the update expression would just use

> `SET listing[${listingIndex}]= list_append(listings, :listingToAttach)`

(using typeScript)